# OpenSSH as a SOCKS5 Proxy *Client*

Tags: ssh, proxy, openssh, ssh-tunnel, socks-proxy

It seems that the OpenSSH client lacks built-in support to act as a *client* of a SOCKS5 proxy. Everything I've found online makes use of **netcat** to achieve the desired effect.

Am I correct that the OpenSSH client does lack built-in support to act as a client of a SOCKS5 proxy?

If so...

Are there alternatives other than **netcat** to accomplish the desired effect? **netcat** is not allowed on our network.

Comment: What do you need the client application to do?  Do you want to access websites through a SOCKS5 proxy server or accomplish some other task?

Comment: The client application is OpenSSH. I want to open an SSH shell session to a host on an isolated network. I have to go through a SOCKS5 proxy to reach the isolated network, but OpenSSH seems to lack the ability to act as a SOCKS5 proxy *client*. (It can, of course, act as a SOCKS5 proxy *server*, but that is unrelated to my question.)

Put differently, the OpenSSH *client* seems to be SOCKS5-unaware. I am looking for confirmation on whether or not I am correct in making this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSH client does not have support for SOCKS protocol. It does not make sense to implement it in OpenSSH itself, because there are other specialized tool (`netcat`) doing it and OpenSSH can work with them (using `ProxyCommand`).

It is the logic of [UNIX philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy):

> Smaller programs are not only easier to write, optimize, and maintain; they are easier to delete when deprecated.

If you need it, talk with your system administrator to allow it for you. If it will not help, install it on your own (it is just few hundred lines of code that you can compile by your own -- pick it up for example [here](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/regress/netcat.c)).